# Get data from form in AngularJS without using two-way data binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The code works with two-way data binding. But I have this constraint, no `=` but `<`.

When I run for the first time the application, the text inputs will have initial hard-coded values. I want to be able to write new values in the inputs and send them to the controller.

Is this possible in one-way data binding?

I will put my code to be more clear.

This is my controller:

```
class DemandCtrl {
    constructor(ChartDataService) {
        this.ChartDataService = ChartDataService;
        debugger;
        this.dataa = {
            from: '10/01/2017',
            to:  '10/03/2017'
        };
    }

    $onInit() {
        getData.call(null, this);       
    }

    update() {
        getData.call(null, this);   
    }

function getData(DemandCtrl) {
    debugger;
    DemandCtrl.ChartDataService.getData(DemandCtrl.dataa).then(result => {
        DemandCtrl.result = result.data;
        getChart(result.data);
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
}

...

DemandCtrl.$inject = ['ChartDataService'];

export const Demand = {
    bindings: {
        data: '<'
    },
    templateUrl: demandPageHtml,
    controller: DemandCtrl
};
```

This is the html page:

```
<div class="demand page">        
    <rtm-nav from="$ctrl.dataa.from", to="$ctrl.dataa.to", submit="$ctrl.update()">         
    </rtm-nav>      
</div>
```

And rtm-nav component:

```
<div class="rtm-nav">
    <div ng-app>
    <form ng-submit="$ctrl.submit()">
        <label>From:
            <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="$ctrl.from">
        </label>
        <label>To:
            <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="$ctrl.to">
        </label>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Apply" />
    </form> 
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the controller of the component. If I change `<` to `=`, everything works as I want but can I do it without changing it?

```
const rtmNav = {
    bindings: {
        from:'<',
        to:'<',
        submit: '&'
    },
    controller: angular.noop,
    templateUrl: require('./rtmNav.html')
}

export default rtmNav;
```

Comment: Could you mention version of AngularJS?

Comment: Use the [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) on the `<input>` elements and output changes with expression, `'&'` binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using [this way](https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-3-isolate-scope-and-function-parameters).

In the component it must be added an object literal to `submit`:

```
<div ng-app>        
        <form ng-submit="$ctrl.submit({from:$ctrl.from, to:$ctrl.to})">
            <label>From:
                <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="$ctrl.from">
            </label>
            <label>To:
                <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="$ctrl.to">
            </label>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Apply" />
        </form> 
    </div>
```

Update method must be converted to look like this:

```
update = (from, to) => { 

    this.dataa.from = from;
    this.dataa.to = to;   
    getData.call(null, this);

 }
```

And in the component in html page must be added `from` and `to` as parameters to the function:

```
<rtm-nav from="$ctrl.dataa.from" to="$ctrl.dataa.to"
         submit="$ctrl.update(from, to)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive on the `<input>` elements:

```
<div class="rtm-nav">
    <div ng-app>
    <form ng-submit="$ctrl.submit()">
        <label>From:
            <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="$ctrl.from"
                   ng-change="fromChange({$value: $ctrl.from})" />
        </label>
        <label>To:
            <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="$ctrl.to"
                   ng-change="toChange({$value: $ctrl.to})" />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Apply" />
    </form> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Output changes with expression, `'&'` binding:

```
const rtmNav = {
    bindings: {
        from:'<',
        fromChange: '&',
        to:'<',
        toChange: '&',
        submit: '&'
    },
    controller: angular.noop,
    templateUrl: require('./rtmNav.html')
}
```

Usage:

```
<rtm-nav from="$ctrl.dataa.from" to="$ctrl.dataa.to"
         from-change="$ctrl.dataa.from = $value"
         to-change="$ctrl.dataa.to = $value"
         submit="$ctrl.update()" >         
</rtm-nav>
```

Comment: I tried with your approach, still doesn't work well. When I launch the application it renders the chart for the hard-coded inputs, if I write other values and click Apply it does the re-render for the same hard-coded values. Looked in Network and it does the same data call